# Accepting both List<T> and T on a Ressource method

Tags: jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I'm trying to implement a POST method which accepts either a single item (T) or a list of items (List) in a REST-full manner.

I've tried implementing only the ressource method using a list

`@POST public Response createItems(List<T> items);`

But that wasn't enough so I tried overriding the method

`@POST public Response createItems(List<T> items);`

`@POST public Response createItem(T item);`

But jersey could not resolve the ambiguity. 
Would there be a way to make this work using features offered by Jersey or Jackson? I'd rather be able to only define one method which accepts a `List<T>` and that the serialization converts a single item to a list.

Comment: The DeserializationFeature [ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) may work in your case. It can be configured on the [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#configure%28com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature,%20boolean%29).

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Would you mind answering the question so I could mark your accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DeserializationFeature [ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) may work in your case. It can be configured on the [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#configure%28com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature,%20boolean%29).